# priority between setTimeout and setImmediate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read this on the node [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) :

> #### setImmediate(callback, [arg], [...])
>
> To schedule the "immediate" execution of callback after I/O events callbacks and **before `setTimeout`** and `setInterval`

However, I see the opposite.
`setTimeout` is executed before `setImmediate`.
Does someone have an explenation for this behavior, or any documentation on the node event loop ?

Thanks :)

code :

```
var index = 0;

function test(name) {
    console.log((index++) + " " + name);
}

setImmediate(function() {
    test("setImmediate");
})

setTimeout(function() {
    test("setTimeout");
}, 0);

process.nextTick(function() {
    test("nextTick");
})

test("directCall");
```

output :

```
0 directCall
1 nextTick
2 setTimeout
3 setImmediate
```

Comment: When I run your code (on node v0.10.31) I get: 0 directCall
1 nextTick
2 setImmediate
3 setTimeout

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check this [github issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6034)

> The event loop cycle is timers -> I/O -> immediates, rinse and repeat.
>   The documentation is correct but incomplete: it doesn't mention that
>   when you haven't entered the event loop yet (as is the case in your
>   example), then timers come first - but only on the first tick. (In
>   master. To complicate matters, things work slightly less deterministic
>   in v0.10.)